# Chart sheet in Excel not working when second sheet open with all cells selected

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have a weird situation with a chart sheet in excel vba. I normally have a Sheet with data and a button with a macro that creates a chart sheet from that data. Like this:

```
Set ChartSheet1 = Charts.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
```

But some users have some code in the excel and it opens with two sheets, one of which has all of the cells selected, both of them empty(
[second sheet with all cells selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEzzn.png)).The data for the chart is on the first sheet and I use nothing from the second sheet (which is empty anyways). 
In this situation when I want to create the chart nothing happens and the focus changes to the 2nd sheet. If I deselect the cells then the chart works. Also if a random range of cells is selected, the chart works fine. It's only when everything's selected.
 Do you have any clue as to why this happens? And is there a solution besides deselecting everything before running the chart creation?

Edited to add code:

```
Sub chartSheet()



Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

If ws Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ""
    Exit Sub
End If

Set ChartSheet1 = Charts.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))

With ChartSheet1
          .SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range(namedRange)
          .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = ws.Range(otherNamedRange)
          .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = ws.Range(namedRange).Item(1)


        While (condition) 

                     .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                     .FullSeriesCollection(X).Values = ws.Range(namedRange)
                     .FullSeriesCollection(X).XValues = ws.Range(otherNamedRange)
                     .FullSeriesCollection(X).Name = ws.Range(namedRange).Item(1)
                X = X + 1

        wend
  end sub
```

Comment: Please show all the relevant code. The issue is not in the line of code you show. Do you have `.Select` or `Selection` statements in your code?

Comment: When you create a chart it typically tries to use any already-selected data.  If the whole sheet is selected then that might cause a problem. Making sure the whole sheet is not selected would be a good solution.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thx for taking the time. The code is more complex, I tried to simplify the situation. I use named ranges to build the chart, I don't use selected ranges. I don't use any selection or .Selects, only "direct" objects. I'll try to shift through the code to find some relevant pieces.

Comment: @AnastasiaV Well, then it looks like what Tim said. Put something like `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select` before you start adding the chart sheet. So the entire cells selection disappears.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thx for the answers. I was hoping to find a solution without having to deselect the ranges as the users might need them. Any other range selected in this second sheet is no problem, only when everything is selected :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround do something like that:

```
Dim OldSelection As Range
Set OldSelection = Selection

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select 'de-select old selection

'run your code here …

OldSelection.Select 're-select it
```

So in the end the same cells are selected as before your code was executed.